# Program crashing while running program for exchanging elements of two arrays

Tags: c, pointers, printf, swap, pointer-arithmetic

I need to input two 1-D arrays Array1 and Array2. And want them to swap elements using pointers. I am using that temp variable method with pointers. This is what I have been doing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    int a[100],b[100],*temp;
    int n,i;
    int *p=a;
    int *q=b;
    printf("Enter size of array1&2:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter array1&2 elements:");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter array1 element [%d]:",i);
        scanf("%d",p+i);
        printf("Enter array2 element [%d]:",i);
        scanf("%d",q+i);
        *temp=*(p+i);
        *(p+i)=*(q+i);
        *(q+i)=*temp;
    }
    printf("Array1 elements: ");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d/n",*p+i);
    }
    printf("Array2 elements: ");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d\n",*q+i);
    }
}
```

But after entering 1 value for each array, the output crashes.
Where am I messing up?

Comment: temp is an uninitialized pointer. You attempt to dereference it. That is an error and undefined behavior. Also there is no reason to be using a pointer here, you should just be using an int instead.

Comment: To check such code, you can use Compiler Explorer. For example, here https://godbolt.org/z/vYcTqcvbq the compiler and the analyzer would issue that the variable is used in a wrong way. Read more: https://pvs-studio.com/en/blog/posts/cpp/0959/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the variable `temp` as having the type `int` instead of `int *`.

```
int a[100],b[100],temp;
```

and then write

```
    temp = *(p+i);
    *(p+i) = *(q+i);
    *(q+i) = temp;
```

Otherwise you are trying to dereference the uninitialized pointer `temp` with an indeterminate value that invokes undefined behavior.

Also in the calls of `printf` you are incorrectly using the pointer arithmetic.

For example instead of

```
printf("%d/n",*p+i);
```

write

```
printf("%d/n",*( p+i ));
```

Otherwise you are outputting the value of the first element of the array plus the value of `i`.